# In example of react-native-router-flux drawer working with tab but not working with customNavBar

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

#### Version

- react-native-router-flux v4.1.0-beta.2
- react v16.8.3
- react-native v0.59.1

I am testing react-native example of react-native-router-flux. Drawer is working fine with Tabs but when I tried with customNacBar its not working

#### Expected behaviour

When user click on hamburger menu icon drawer should open.

#### Actual behaviour

When user click on hamburger menu icon drawer is not opening.

#### Steps to reproduce

Take pull and run react-native example and try to implement drawer with customNavBar.
[react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

#### Reproducible Demo

```
<Drawer
    hideNavBar
    key="drawer"
    onExit={() => {
    console.log('Drawer closed');
    }}
    onEnter={() => {
    console.log('Drawer opened');
    }}
    contentComponent={DrawerContent}
    drawerImage={MenuIcon}
    drawerWidth={300}>
    <Scene hideNavBar panHandlers={null}>
    <Stack key="customNavBar" hideTabBar headerLayoutPreset="center">
        <Scene key="customNavBar1" title="CustomNavBar 1" navBar={CustomNavBar} component={CustomNavBarView} back />
        <Scene key="customNavBar2" title="CustomNavBar 2" navBar={CustomNavBar} component={CustomNavBarView} back />
        <Scene key="customNavBar3" title="Another CustomNavBar" navBar={CustomNavBar2} component={CustomNavBarView} back />
        <Scene key="hiddenNavBar" title="hiddenNavBar" component={CustomNavBarView} hideNavBar={true} back />
    </Stack>
    </Scene>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Can you please post your `CustomNavBar` component? The problem is most probably there